# How to set border radius of some corner only with CSS

Tags: html, css

[image]

As shown above, can I give a radius to the top parts only and not to bottom or sometimes to bottom not to top?

And is there any idea to give border radius to one corner only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like `border-radius:top-left top-right bottom-right bottom-left`,

```
div{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px; 
    background: black;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mkhTE/1/)**

Comment: Should really explain that the four values equate to top, right, bottom, left in that order. but in border radius its top-left, top-right, bottom-right, bottom-left

Comment: @user2253835 Updated the answer with explanation

Answer (score 3):

Either use border-radius, such as:

```
border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
```

Or, for the top left border, you can be more specific with:

```
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the CSS for the rounded corners only on a div with a class of box:

`.box {
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}`

You may also find this helpful: http://css3generator.com/

**Edit:** [Apparently](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) you don't need the webkit prefix anymore!