# Rounded corners only on some corners in css

Tags: css

Is it possible to create a rounded corner using css where I only get rounding on some specific corner rather than all of the corners? Currently I am using:

```
  -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
  -moz-border-radius: 7px;
  border-radius: 7px;
```

But I don't see any way to specifying the top left or some other corner. I want the other corners to remain square.

Comment: try it out like this,`border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px;`
Demo: http://jsbin.com/acumag/1/edit

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16036486/how-to-set-border-radius-of-some-corner-only-with-css

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can do it like

```
border-radius: 5px 10px 15px 20px; /* This is a short hand syntax */
```

The above syntax works like a fan, starting from `5px` and ends on `20px`, just added a diagram below, the arrow in there depicts the start of the shorthand syntax flow.

[image]

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MfEPv/)

To specify a particular radius, you can use property like

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
```

Which is equivalent to

```
border-radius: 10px 0 0 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ta8mR/12/)

- border-radius-top-left
- border-radius-top-right
- border-radius-bottom-left
- border-radius-bottom-right

  ```
  border-radius: 5px 0 10px 0;
  ```

  [image]

For more information visit **[this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp)** website.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this : -

```
border-radius: <specific_value>px <specific_value>px <specific_value>px <specific_value>px
```

these 4 values represent the different corners in a clock-wise manner .

Answer (score 1):

```
.rounded-corners {
   -moz-border-radius: 20px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 20px;\
    border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Changes can be made like this,

```
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0px;
     border-top-left-radius: 0px;
     border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0px;
     border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
     border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple to create a rounded border by specifying a particular corner :-

If u want to create the top left corner rounded and all other corners straight ,then use this code instead of "border-radius" and give your desired value in pixels

```
border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
```

you can do this in a differnt way also :-

border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 0px ;

where the first one in for top-left corner(10px) , second is for top-right corner (0px) , third is for bottom-right corner (0px) and the fourth is for bottom-left corner (0px).

by this , only top-left corner will be made rounded and all other corners will remain the same